How can I gradually speed up or slow down multiple keyframes
I am trying to gradually slow or speed up particular keyframes. Not just making the whole thing a different speed. I have found one way of finally doing it via the NLA editor but I am looking to see if it can be done else where such as the timeline, dope sheet, graph editor, etc.
Things I have attempted already...
Scaling in timeline with S (It is close but it seems to not be able to give a gradual scaling and makes all keyframes seperate the same.
Porportional Editing in graph editor scaling with S about the horizontal axis (almost exactly what im looking for but when scaling sections it seems to push back [or suck in depending on if I am making faster or slower] other frames so that those parts are affected). For example if I want a part in the middle to be slower, it will scruch the beginning and ending of the section making those parts faster. I try to move the Key frames to compensate for this but it starts to become a manual hassle.

You've hit upon a common problem for Blender animators. At the time of writing this answer, Blender's other editors have features like… edits only affecting the selection, edit groups, locking, masking, and hiding—features which do not exist for keyframes.
Your Proportional Editing approach is the right one, but what to do about the problem of the editing going in both directions and messing up other keyframes?
The brokenness or hassle of the workflow will vary, but I've fixed small damage using the Pose Library to store and restore a frame or two,
or moving the retiming to a separate Action for work which will cause more dramatic damage.
Or, nauseatingly kludgy though it may be, there's what I do most often; a copy-paste routine to restore an edit's inadvertently-moved keyframes.

Select the keyframes to be retimed
Ctrl+I to Select → Invert
Ctrl+C to Copy
Perform the proportional edits
X or Key → Delete the selected keyframes
Ctrl+V Paste
In the popup/F9 to Edit → Adjust Last Operation, choose Frame Offset: No Offset.

Here's what that might look like if I needed to speed up some middle portion of an animation, but with other keyframes left alone in time, plus that proportional-edit scale so that the speed-up itself tapers off.


Sorry for late followup but thank you this helps
